# Howswap resources with IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, hotswap

I develop a simple standalone application without any application server. Can IDEA do hotswap with resources (hotswap works with classes fine when I do rebuild). Also I use gradle as a build system, my application read static resources from "src/main/resources". I just want that when I do rebuild my application could download newer version of my resouce file without restart.

I use this code to read resources:

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(name)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, IDEA hotswaps changes made to file. You have 2 options:

- right click on resource and select "Compile '[resource name]'"
- go to "Gradle" pane and run "Project > Tasks > build > assemble"

Both of them will pick up resource changes and make them available with no need to restart Debug session.

Comment: Works only with classes. When I do build my resources change in "out/production/..", but inside my application old version of file

Comment: How do you start your application (Using IDEA Run/Debug). Or you are connecting to debug remotely? What kind of application is that (simple Java, Webapp, ..)?